# Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

To use react router v4, I have added some configuration in webpack and package.json file . There is a error when I do `npm start`.

Error

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'devServer'. These properties are valid:
   object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
```

Webpack File(webpack.config.js)

```
var path = require("path"),
    DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                query:
                    {
                        presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                    }
            }
        ],
        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
        }
    }

};

module.exports = config;
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactcorepoc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "react with .net core",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --history-api-fallback",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html "
  },
  "author": "Ankur",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-amplify": "^0.4.8",
    "aws-amplify-react": "^0.1.54",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.12.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

App.js

```
class APP extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Route path="/" component={loginComponent} />
                    <Route path="/GetAllAccounts" component={AccountComponent} />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

There is something basic that is missing here, Suggestions ?

Comment: Remove `devServer: { historyApiFallback: true }` and see what happens.

Comment: @Tholle when I remove devServer: { historyApiFallback: true } in webpack.config.js it does not give error on the command line. However When I http://localhost:8081/ on the browser it gives a blank page with a error msg This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding exactly what your `build` script does. Try adding a new one, e.g. `test`, and try this: `"test": "webpack-dev-server"`

Comment: Build: Script uses copy command of unix to copy my index.html from src folder to dist  index.html .also  you know what this does webpack-dev-server  the reaming part is for hot reloading and history api call back

Comment: Yes, but you should not have to do `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` simultaneously.

Comment: @Tholle removed it too, still the same error when i browse the page in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've placed the devServer object in the wrong place.

You've defined

```
var config = {
    ...
    module: {
        ...
        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
        }
    }
}
```

but you probably meant

```
var config = {
    ...
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    }
}
```

Moving devServer outside module should fix the issue and redirect your 404s.